# Term for the idea that regardless of our philosophy, only the observable/physical matters

Tags: reference-request, terminology, rationality, definitions, axiom

I'm looking for terms that define the following presuppositions:

1. every action should be valued based on its outcomes, not choosing is a choice
2. impact of an action must be valued based on the observable change of the world, regardless of the actor
3. in every moment, one has to decide for the present, counting with all options, regardless of the [sunk costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost).

I'll be glad for every suggestion, thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a term that would encompass multiple definitions; I don't think the "term" you're looking for exists.

Comment: I'm looking for a term that would encompass any of them

Comment: This is a version of [consequentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/) close to [act utilitarianism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/util-a-r/).

Comment: @Conifold Consequentialism it is, thank you :)